# Is it possible to have an outline and padding/margins of all containers in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

This is something that would be very useful during development. For example, my android phone allows "Show Layout Boundaries" as a Developer Option, e.g.

[image]

With this, I can see outlines of all layouts, including the padding and margins. Is there something like this in WPF that I could use to see how each element on the screen relates to the other elements?

Answer (score 1):

In WPF the only thing that seems to be close it is [`ShowGridLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines(v=vs.110).aspx) property in `Grid`:

> Enabling `Grid` lines creates dotted lines around all the elements within a `Grid`. Only dotted lines are available because this property is intended as a design tool to debug layout problems and is not intended for use in production quality code. If you want lines inside a `Grid`, style the elements within the `Grid` to have borders.

Example:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" ... />
```

[image]

For more information, see this link:

[`ShowGridLines Property Allows You to See Individual Cells in Grid`](http://wpf.2000things.com/tag/showgridlines)

Answer (score 1):

While the program is running, you might be interested in [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), which lets you inspect and highlight arbitrary elements of the interface and explode the window into a 3D view.  It's not the same visual as you're looking for, but similarly useful.